# How Pex can deal with generics?

Tags: generics, pex

How Pex can deal with generics?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Agree, the question is pretty unclear.  Maybe this will help?: http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/briankel/Pex-Automated-Exploratory-Testing-for-NET

Answer (score 1):

Pex can explore generic methods if thats what you mean. you can use 
`[PexGenericArguments( params Type[]  types)]`
to supply the generic arguments pex should use. you can also use the attribute multiple times to get it to use multiple combinations of type arguments